Google Library API to Photo Picker - do you have to use Google's UI?
I have a website for pilots that allows people to add images to a flight entry.  I've long had functionality that would use the Google Photo Auth API to preview the Google Photos that are on the date of the flight, and click on them to attach to their flight.  Works great, no need to leave the website and lose the context of their in-progress flight, and no need to search through a huge mess of photos since it's already restricted to the date of the flight.
But it looks like Google is planning to end the photoslibrary.readonly next March, and they want people to migrate to their Picker UI.  But in looking at the UI, it appears that it requires using Google's user interface, and which means leaving the context of what you're already entering.
Am I missing something?  Is there any way to continue to offer this functionality "in situ" (without leaving my website) with the picker APIs?

It appears so, and it looks like if you use window.open(..., "_blank"), then you don't have to leave your own website, so I think I can do that.

That is my understanding as well, you have to use the picker UI provided by them.
Unfortunately, this means opening a NEW WINDOW/TAB; as the pickerUri cannot be shown in an iframe.
This is a very awkward workflow.
I requested that they add some ability to add a return uri to either the picker UI or the app configuration.
Please upvote/add comments to the issue if you think it would be helpful - that may help it get some movement.
See here.
